# why $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2] \ncong \mathbb Z[\sqrt 3]$?

Tags: ring-theory

The following is a question from section $3.11$ of the book **An introduction to abstract algebra** by *Allenby*:

> Explain intuitively why $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2] \ncong \mathbb Z[\sqrt 3]$.back your intuition with proof.
>
> **Note**:*this example not only says that $\theta: a+b\sqrt 2 \mapsto a+b\sqrt 3$ is not isomorphism .It says no isomorphism can be found at all - no matter how clever choice of mapping you try to make* ..

I can't see what's the intution behind this ..can anyone provide some hint on this...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Hint: $2$ is a square in the first ring. Is it a square in the second?

Comment: if I've to explain this using the property of isomorphism how should I do it...

Comment: @coool What have you tried? I have given you 95% of the answer.

Comment: @coool You know that $\theta(1) = 1$, don't you? So what is $\theta(2)$?

Comment: @DanielFischer sorry to ask this but how is $\theta(1) = 1$?Please help...

Comment: @kittuu $\theta(x) = \theta(1\cdot x) = \theta(1)\cdot \theta(x)$. Pick an $x$ with $\theta(x)\neq 0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks ...

Answer (score 2):

*Proof:* Suppose that there exists an isomorphism $\psi : \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}] \to \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$. Consider $x = 0 + 1\sqrt{2} = \sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$

Note that since $\psi$ is an isomorphism, $\psi(1) = 1$. Hence $\psi(2) = \psi(1 + 1) = \psi(1) + \psi(1) = 2$. Now note also that $\psi(2) = \psi(\sqrt{2}\cdot \sqrt{2}) = \psi(\sqrt{2})\cdot \psi(\sqrt{2}) = \left(\psi(\sqrt{2})\right)^2 = 2$. Since $\psi(\sqrt{2}) \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ we must have $\psi(\sqrt{2}) = a+b\sqrt{3}$ for some $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$, but then we have $\left(\psi(\sqrt{2})\right)^2 = a^2 + 2ab\sqrt{3} + b^2\sqrt{3}$ Since $\left(\psi(\sqrt{2})\right)^2 = 2$ we must have $b = 0$ and thus have $\left(\psi(\sqrt{2})\right)^2 = a^2$. Thus $a = \pm \sqrt{2}$, hence $\psi(\sqrt{2}) = \pm\sqrt{2} \not\in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ a contradiction. Thus no such isomorphism exists. $\square$

Comment: Did you mean to write $\left(\psi\left(\sqrt 2\right)\right)^2=a^2+2ab\sqrt 3+\color{red}3b^2$ instead?

Answer (score 1):

let $\sqrt {2}\in \mathbb {Z}[\sqrt{2}]$

$\phi(\sqrt {2 })^2= \phi (2) =2 $

$\phi (\sqrt {2 })= \pm \sqrt {2} \not\in \mathbb {Z} \sqrt{3} $

Comment: The last claim needs proof of course, but it's easy.