# Why $\Omega_{K}^{X^2-2}\cong\Omega_{K}^{X^2-3}$ for $K=\mathbb{F}_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra

We have seen that $\Omega_{\mathbb{Q}}^{X^2-2}\ncong\Omega_{\mathbb{Q}}^{X^2-3}$ from [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/997758/218659)

But why  $\Omega_{K}^{X^2-2}\cong\Omega_{K}^{X^2-3}$ for $K=\mathbb{F}_5$?

$\Omega$ being the splittingfield of the polynomial over the given field.

Comment: What does this $\Omega$ notation mean?

Comment: The splittingfield of the polynomial over the given field

Comment: Once you know that a finite field is uniquely determined by its cardinality, it suffices to verify that $x^2 - 2$ and $x^2 - 3$ are either both reducible or both irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_5$. It happens that they're both irreducible, so the splitting field is $\mathbb{F}_{25}$ in both cases.

Comment: What if i consider your comment as an answer?